# Ninject, WebAPI and ExceptionFilterAttribute being called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ninject

Good morning all,

I noticed strange behavior of Ninject (at least I think that it is the problem) in my project. The situation is the following. I use

```
Ninject.3.0.2-unstable-9028
Ninject.Extensions.Factory.3.0.1.0
Ninject.Web.Common.3.0.2-unstable-9012
Ninject.Web.WebApi-RC.3.0.0.22
```

I changed the **NinjectWebCommon.cs** and added code with my bindings. I have a **WebApiConfig.cs** which configures global exceptions handler

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Authentication token handler.
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TokenAuthenticationHandler());

    // Exceptions handler.
    config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionsHandler());
    ...
 }
```

and I have an exceptions handler class

```
public class ExceptionsHandler : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    ...
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {

        ...
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(httpStatusCode, response);
    }
}
```

Now, when the request comes to the API it first gets to **TokenAuthenticationHandler()** object which does its magic and calls

```
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

Then WebAPI controller kicks in and does its magic. In case of exception, it gets thrown and OnException of ExceptionsHandler gets called. The problem is that when **OnException** finishes its job, It gets called again with same context and I can't find the reason why.

I don't configure it twice. I don't have extra records in web.config. It started happening when I started using **Ninject.Web.WebAPI-RC** library. Before that I was using custom made Resolvers and Contexts classes that worked well, but, didn't dispose Ninject created objects. So, I decided to use what works. And everything do work except that for some reason OnException gets called twice.

If I remove

```
config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionsHandler());
```

from **WebApiConfig.cs** then it doesn't get called at all.

I think that Ninject has something to do with it, but I can't understand why it happens.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to not use Ninject.Web.WebAPI-RC as time of writing. It is not stable, you should stick with the code you had before. IF you need to perform DI for your filters, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614139/ninject-property-injection-in-webapi-custom-exceptionfilterattribute-not-working/21635413#21635413

Comment: The problem with code I was using before is that extensions like InScopeRequest() weren't working. Objects created by Ninject weren't disposed correctly after the request to the Web API controller was done.

Comment: Which DependencyResolver were you using? Check this implementation, I think you'd be okay with that https://gist.github.com/cvbarros/8783363

Comment: Thank you. I was using the following http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/ classes. I have tried using ones provided by you. I have also removed Ninject.Web.WebAPI from my references and started using only stable versions Ninject, Ninject.Web.Common but now my InRequestScope objects are not getting disposed when the request is finished as well as properties with [Inject] attributes are not getting populated. I think I will live with what I had before until I will find a solution... Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
 public class ExceptionsHandler : ExceptionFilterAttribute
 {
    ...
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {

      ...
       context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(httpStatusCode, response);
    }
 }
```

This worked for me.. =)

Comment: This worked for me. I think the exception was handled by controller and action too.

Comment: It worked like magic.  But I still don't understand why it works. By default, `ExceptionFilterAttribute` is has attribusage to `.Class` and `.Method`, which would cover controller and action.  What does `.All` actually enable that is not covered otherwise?